# Java NIO (Netty): Exceptionhandling in Downstream Hanlders/Chain

Tags: java, nio, netty

could someone please explain to me, how in netty "Downstream Exceptions" are handeled? According to the javadoc there are no Downstream exceptions:

http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/ExceptionEvent.html

Given the case that in one of my downstream handlers an exception occures OR in the I/0 Thread itself, where can these errors be catched and handeled?

thank you very much
tom

Answer (score 3):

If an exception is raised in your handler, it always triggers an upstream exception event.  It doesn't matter if the exception was raised by an upstream or a downstream handler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `SimpleChannelDownstreamHandler` doesn't have any exception handling method, as you say.  Could you rather use a plain old `SimpleChannelHandler`, and use a downstream method, like `writeRequested(...)`? (That is, just move your code to that method).  Then you could use `exceptionCaught(...)` when it throws an exception.